# How do academics show up on Google's "knowledge panel"?

Tags: google-scholar

I am not sure if this is really a question for AcademiaExchange; however, given the context of the question, I thought this may indeed be the appropriate platform: How does Google's Knowledge Panel exactly work? I know very prominent academics both at my current institution, as well as my previous one (e.g. one of whom is a full professor, and another one who is an associate professor), who when Googled do not own their own knowledge panels, despite owning Google Scholar profiles, personal University web pages, as well as their personal websites. Yet, I, as an early career researcher (postdoc) seem to have my own knowledge panel, despite having a minute fraction of their publications and working at the same institution as they do. My question is, how does Google's algorithm decide who gets a knowledge panel and who doesn't?

Comment: Having no idea what a knowledge panel is supposed to be, I don’t know. No desire to find out, much less manage it…

Comment: Directly ask Google, then self-asnwer your own question here!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you made me look.

At [Google itself](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9163198?hl=en) one finds:

> Knowledge panels are automatically generated, and information that appears in a knowledge panel comes from various sources across the web. In some cases, we may work with data partners who provide authoritative data on specific topics like movies or music, and combine that data with information from other open web sources.

> We also know that entities whose information is included in knowledge panels (like prominent individuals or the creators of a television show) are self-authoritative, and we provide ways for these entities to provide direct feedback.

So it is expected that folks might not even know about a knowledge panel about them.

Comment: Also, some folks might have a  knowledge panel about them and not want one.

Comment: @TerryLoring - I don’t want one, but Google might make one for me. No indication there is an opt-out…